# "Учитывая, что..."

Tags: грамотная-речь, деепричастный-оборот

*Учитывая, что на выступлении будут специалисты, то выглядеть я буду не лучшим образом.*

Посмотрел, подобные конструкции часто встречаются, и на слух вроде бы звучат нормально. Но правильно ли так использовать деепричастие (оборот)? Может, это какой-то особый случай, что-то наподобие вводного предложения?..

Или вот еще:
*Учитывая предысторию, это не та ситуация, в которой нужно делать выбор*.

Здесь, чтобы избежать сомнений, можно написать так:
*Если учитывать предысторию, то это не та ситуация*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Варианты редактирования

1. **Учитывая**, что на выступлении будут специалисты,  выглядеть я буду не лучшим образом.  При отсутствии ***ТО*** здесь значение **причины** (так как на выступлении будут специалисты).

Если **учесть**, что на выступлении будут специалисты,  выглядеть я буду не лучшим образом. Значение условия.

2. ***Учитывая** предысторию, это не та ситуация, в которой нужно делать выбор*.  Деепричастный оборот употреблен **неверно.**

***Если учесть** предысторию, то это не та ситуация, в которой нужно делать выбор.*

***С учетом предыстории,** это не та ситуация, в которой нужно делать выбор.*

Comment: Спасибо! Да, "то" там лишнее. Т.е. получается, что этот оборот "не совсем" деепричастный? Например, вот еще: "Учитывая, что крылатых вестников любили и ждали только на заставе, шанс у птиц исчезнуть по дороге был весьма велик". И таких примеров куча. Если можно заменить на "так как" (значение причины), то всё нормально? Независимо от того, что деепричастие не относится к глаголу?

Comment: А обязательно вместо "учитывать" надо "учесть"?

Comment: Такие предложения во многом корректируются на слух. У каждого варианта свои проблемы. .Значение условия и причины близки,  и там важен вид деепричастия. Деепричастия НСВ обозначают одновременное действие, а для условия нужно завершенное действие.  (Для причины это не требуется.) В первом предложении  деепричастие должно относиться к подлежащему:   я буду учитывать, я буду выглядеть.  Вроде бы так.

Comment: "Учитывая, что крылатых вестников любили и ждали только на заставе, шанс у птиц исчезнуть по дороге был весьма велик".  А здесь неверное употребление оборота, разные  подлежащие.

Comment: "Учитывая, что личности обеих сторон мне неизвестны, дело казалось тупиковым". Тоже неверно. Короче, каждое предложение надо отдельно разбирать...